# Android - Phonegap inner active interaction

Tags: android, cordova

Could someone please provide me with some code or a tuorial in order to add inner active into my app.

What I have currently done:
1 - Signed up and registered to inner active
2 - Downloaded the sdk and added the external jar to my eclipse project

However, how can I do the following:
1 - Add banner ads onto the bottom of my app pages
2 - Refresh these ads every 15 seconds

Bare in mind I am using phonegap and therefore need to implement this using HTML and JavaScript.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Nirit and I'm a support manager at inneractive.

At the end of the registration process you would be able to download our SDKs.

The Android SDK is designed for Java developers and is not practical for HTML / JavaScript implementations.

However, the **Widgets (generic version) SDK** is suitable with JavaScript, you are more than welcome to download it and review our step-by-step integration guideline.

Please feel free to contact me if you have any further questions or comments.

Looking forward to start working with you,
Best Regards,
Nirit (support@inner-active.com).

Comment: Could you please provide a link where i can find this SDK, Thanks

Comment: Please login to your Dashboard first, otherwise, the link won't work for you. [link](http://console.inner-active.com/iamp/publisher/downloadsdk?sdk=files/inneractiveAdSDK-Widgets-v1.6.zip)

Comment: is this still the same think as ther inner active SDK? Also, I cannot seem to find the javascript file to attach within my project. Thanks

Comment: Sorry one other thing can i refresh my banner ads every 15 seconds using this widget SDK?

Comment: This is a different SDK which is suitable with JavaScript.
You don’t have to add any file but to call the innerActive.js script from your main html widget file.
Please follow our SDK step-by-step guideline in order to better understand the integration process.
On this specific SDK please use JavaScript’s setInterval() method to refresh the banner.
Nirit (support@inner-active.com).

Comment: Hi, I am coming back to this and would like to implement both banner ads and full screen ads (with some of my own text underneath the ad). However, I cannot work out how to implement this, the link above now takes me to serveral different SDK and is not clear which one i need to download.

Comment: Can you please proivde some clear guidelines how i can implement these ads in javascript, prefereably some example code and wheather i need to include any SDK within my apps java build library?

Comment: Finally, would i be able to display my own ads or others if the internet is not available? Thanks

Comment: @LandLPartners I think that's too many questions to get a proper answer. Focus on one thing and get over any obstacles with that. Then, raise a new question here or on the Inner Active site.